# Swiper.js navigation issue in FireFox

Tags: swiper.js

I've got a fairly simple swiper setup. Except that I'm using navigation buttons, fraction pagination, AND I want to use bullets as well. Everything works beautifully in every browser except FireFox. In FireFox, when I click get to the last slide with the navigation buttons, it jumps up to the top of the page. It advances to the 1st slide again, but it jumps up. Same going the other direction. It only starts after I've gone through the full cycle of slides, forwards or backwards. Not when I click on individual navigation dots, or just go back and forth within the slides. It only happens when it's time to loop. The hell of it is, this same script works perfectly well in a plain html file. But this instance is on WordPress, so I'm wondering if something there is interfering. I don't have any console errors though. Everything *seems* to work fine otherwise.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".vopaSwiper", {
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-next-button",
    prevEl: ".swiper-prev-button"
  },
  effect: "fade",
  loop: true,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    type: "fraction",
  },

  // Add a callback for onInit and onSlideChange to update bullets
  on: {
    init: function() {
      createBullets(this);
    },
    slideChange: function() {
      updateBullets(this);
    }
  }
});

function createBullets(swiper) {
  var bulletsContainer = document.querySelector('.swiper-bullets');
  if (!bulletsContainer) return;

  // Clear existing bullets
  bulletsContainer.innerHTML = '';

  // Create new bullets
  swiper.slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
    var bullet = document.createElement('span');
    bullet.className = 'swiper-bullet';
    bullet.addEventListener('click', () => swiper.slideTo(index));
    bulletsContainer.appendChild(bullet);
  });

  // Initial update for bullets
  updateBullets(swiper);
}

function updateBullets(swiper) {
  var bullets = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-bullets .swiper-bullet');
  bullets.forEach((bullet, index) => {
    if (index === swiper.realIndex) {
      bullet.classList.add('active');
    } else {
      bullet.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#MiniCarousel {
  .caption {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
  }
  .vopaSwiper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 888;
  }
  .main {
    padding: 42px 0 30px;
    position: relative;
    @media screen and (max-width: 930px) {
      flex-direction: column-reverse;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
  }
  p.sub-header {
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
    font-style: italic;
  }
  p.link {
    text-align: center;
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      text-align: left;
    }
  }
  .btn {
    transition-delay: 0.6s;
    margin: 1rem auto 2rem auto;
  }
  .ratio {
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    @media screen and (max-width: 930px) {
      margin-bottom: 56px;
    }
    .slide-bg {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      box-shadow: 1.25rem 1.375rem 2.5rem 0rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.92);
      position: relative;
    }
  }
  .swiper-pagination {
    width: auto;
    font-size: .7rem;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .button-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    @media screen and (max-width: 930px) {
      width: 100%;
      justify-content: space-between;
      padding: 0 0 0 1rem;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
      padding: 0 1rem;
    }
    svg {
      width: 28px;
    }
    .swiper-button {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 40%, transparent 0%);
      background-size: 275% 100%;
      background-position: right bottom;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 60px;
      &:hover {
        background-color: #000;
        background-position: left bottom;
        svg {
          stroke: #000;
        }
      }
    }
    .swiper-button+.swiper-button {
      margin-top: 16px;
      @media screen and (max-width: 930px) {
        margin-left: 16px;
      }
    }
    .swiper-prev-button {
      background: linear-gradient(to left, gold 40%, transparent 0%);
      background-size: 300% 100%;
      background-position: left bottom;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
      svg {
        transform: rotate(-180deg);
      }
      &:hover {
        background-position: right bottom;
      }
    }
  }
  .swiper-bullets {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
    pointer-events: all;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    .swiper-bullet {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 50%;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin: 0 8px;
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: transparent;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px gold;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      @media (min-width: 992px) {
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
      }
      &.active,
      &:active,
      &:hover {
        opacity: 0.7;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
        transform: scale(1.25);
      }
      &::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: gold;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        transform: scale(0);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease;
        transition: transform 0.3s ease;
      }
      &.active::after {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
        transform: scale(1.25);
      }
    }
  }
  .swiper-slide {
    opacity: 0 !important;
    transition: 0.4s;
    .caption>* {
      transform: translateY(-30px);
      opacity: 0;
      transition-duration: 0.8s;
    }
    .swiper-slide .slide-bg {
      transition-duration: 0.6s;
      opacity: 0;
      object-position: 60%;
    }
  }
  .swiper-slide-active {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    .caption>* {
      transform: none;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .slide-bg {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: none;
      object-position: 50%;
    }
  }
  .slide-bg iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -75%;
    content: '';
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 250%;
    min-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<main class="container-fluid">
  <section id="MiniCarousel" class="row justify-content-center position-relative">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-1 order-2 order-lg-1 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div class="swiper-pagination position-relative mb-5 mx-auto"></div>
      <div class="button-wrapper position-relative d-flex flex-row flex-lg-column justify-content-center">
        <div class="swiper-button swiper-prev-button btn btn-primary">
          <svg fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.2" d="M17 8l4 4m0 0l-4 4m4-4H3">
                            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button swiper-next-button btn btn-primary">
          <svg fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="1.2" d="M17 8l4 4m0 0l-4 4m4-4H3">
                            </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 col-lg-7 order-1 order-lg-2 position-relative">
      <div class="vopaSwiper">
        <div class="main-wrapper swiper-wrapper">

          <div class="main swiper-slide" id="ham">
            <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
              <div class="carousel-img">
                <img class="slide-bg position-relative" src="https://vopa.themedev.thepixelpixie.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/vopa-rocks-concert-pic-1.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="caption">
              <p class="sub-header">Caption 2 goes here</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="main swiper-slide" id="dicks">
            <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
              <div class="carousel-img">
                <img class="slide-bg" src="https://vopa.themedev.thepixelpixie.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/dft-jb-bway-sign-scaled.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="caption">
              <p class="sub-header">Caption 4 goes here</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="main swiper-slide" id="cookie">
            <div class="center ratio ratio-16x9">
              <div class="right-side__img">
                <img class="slide-bg" src="https://vopa.themedev.thepixelpixie.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/mercedes.jpg" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="caption">
              <p class="sub-header">Caption goes here 6</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-bullets"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Of course it works here. Ughhhh

Maybe a few more details about my WordPress install will shed some light? I have modernizr, fontawesome, & popper installed in addition to the scripts loaded in the example here. I have not unenqueued jQuery, though I'm generally not using it in my theme. The site has WooCommerce, The Event Plugin, Event Tickets, Yoast SEO, ACF Pro, Gravity Forms, Solid Security, Safe SVG.

Comment: Just an idea. Try to prefix your slider ids _ e.g "slider_cookie". Maybe there is another element e.g. with the id "cookie" that gets targeted (by an event listener or an anchor jump).